# PageFragment and TextView: Why i get an error?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a `PageFragment` composed in this way

```
public class MyPageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mypage, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

If I try to insert a `TextView` and set text in it,

I get an error

> "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type
>   MyPageFragment"` Why? How to fix?

My TextView is

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv.setText(MyVariable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onCreateView

```
  TextView tv = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.tv2);
```

Update :

pls check the below comments

as blackbelt suggested you can use `getView` if you are initalizing textview else where in your fragment.

```
   View v = getView()
   TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
```

Comment: @MariocciRossini you welcome and if it helps mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick once

Comment: I could agree.... but how could I perform the same findViewById outside onCreateView?

Comment: @blackbelt  you could declare textview as a class member initialize in onCreate and use it else where or having view object as a class member and then using the same to initialize textview else where. Correct me if i am wrong. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: or you can use getView() method to perform findViewById instead of keeping a member class

Comment: @blackbelt oh yes `View v = getView()` and then initialize textview